# Woocommerce category thumbnail grid expandable layout

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to create a category page which will have all the categories with thumbnails, on clicking category I would like to show all the product below like Google image layout or you can check this link below.

https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ThumbnailGridExpandingPreview/

On clicking the thumbnail I would like to show all the products related to the clicked category thumbnail.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I was able to show the categories with thumbnails on a page but can't figure out how to show products below that category.

Check this - https://themonk.co.in/sunglasses/

Comment: Why don't you try to include a [woocommerce shortcode](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/) just after…

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Its not possible using shortcodes. Please let me know how is this possible using shortcode?